# How freeze training of particular layer after particular epoches

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to freeze training of first two layers of following code after 3rd epoch. Total epoch is set to 10.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

Answer (score 4):

**How can I "freeze" Keras layers?**

To "freeze" a layer means to exclude it from training, i.e. its weights will never be updated. This is useful in the context of fine-tuning a model or using fixed embeddings for a text input.

You can change the trainable attribute of a layer.

```
for layer in model.layers[:2]:
    layer.trainable = False
```

For this to take effect, you will need to call **compile()** on your model after modifying the trainable property. If you don't you will receive a warning "Discrepancy between trainable weights and collected trainable weights" and all your layers will be still trainable. So:

- Build and compile the model
- Train it for 3 epochs
- Freeze layers you want
- compile the model again
- Train the rest epochs

Comment: I know above mentioned method. Is there any method that doesnot require two time training?

Comment: Have the same question as Hitesh, has this been addressed since 2019?

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
for epoch in range(3):
    model.fit(.., epochs=1)

# save the weights of this model
model.save_weights("weight_file.h5") 

# freeze the layers you want
for layer in model.layers[:2]:
    layer.trainable = False
```

In order to train further with these weights but first two layers frozen, you need to compile the model again.

```
model.compile(..)

# train further    
for epoch in range(3, 10):
    model.fit(..., epochs=1)
```

Comment: It won't work without compiling the model again. You will get the warning after that: "Discrepancy between trainable weights and collected trainable weights". Please see my answer. Secondly why not just model.fit(..., epochs=7) instead that for loop...