# Update a non trainable variable at the beginning of each epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

This question is similar to [Tensorflow Keras modify model variable from callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60102214/tensorflow-keras-modify-model-variable-from-callback). I am unable to get the solution there to work (maybe there have been changes in TensorFlow 2.x since the solution was posted).

Below is demo code. I apologise if there is a typo.

I want to use a callback to update a non trainable variable (`weighted_add_layer.weight`) that affects the output of the layer.

I have tried many variants such as putting `tf.keras.backend.set_value(weighted_add_layer.weight, value)` in `update function`.

In all cases, after the model is compiled, `fit` uses the value of `weighted_add_layer.weight` at the time of compilation and does not update the value later.

```
class WeightedAddLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, weight=0.00, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WeightedAddLayer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.weight = tf.Variable(0., trainable=False)

    def add(self, inputA, inputB):
        return (self.weight * inputA + self.weight * inputB)

    def update(self, weight):
        tf.keras.backend.set_value(self.weight, weight)
        
input_A = tfkl.Input(
    shape=(32),
    batch_size=32,
)

input_B = tfkl.Input(
    shape=(32),
    batch_size=32,
)

weighted_add_layer = WeightedAddLayer()

output = weighted_add_layer.add(input_A, input_B)

model = tfk.Model(
    inputs=[input_A, input_B],
    outputs=[output],
)
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam', loss=losses.MeanSquaredError()
)

# Custom callback function
def update_fun(epoch, steps=50):
    weighted_add_layer.update(
      tf.clip_by_value(
          epoch / steps,
          clip_value_min=tf.constant(0.0),
          clip_value_max=tf.constant(1.0),)
    )
    

# Custom callback
update_callback = tfk.callbacks.LambdaCallback(
    on_epoch_begin=lambda epoch, logs: update_fun(epoch)
)

# train model
history = model.fit(
    x=train_data,
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    validation_data=valid_data,
    callbacks=[update_callback],
)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks much!

Comment: I think it is possible, check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/75435498/9215780

Comment: Interesting you use subclassed callback in that example whereas I was using a lambda callback. Thanks! I will try with your approach as soon as I get the chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This could be an issue with TensorFlow 2.11.0 or my installation or something else I am missing but the use of lambda callbacks was both extremely unstable with my code base and bug checked constantly, and did not do what I wanted. It also led to odd behaviour that made it seem like there was a memory leak. The code for the complete model is very complex and I don't have the time to debug so I am sharing this information with a big FWIW caveat.
2. The code in [Is there a way to make a layer behave differently during forward pass for model.fit() and model.evaluate() in a customised Keras model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75428704/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-layer-behave-differently-during-forward-pass-for-model/75435498#75435498) works. Some pointers:

a. You must have the tf.variable sit inside a layer and non trainable. I could not get this approach to work with a tf.variable outside a layer. That is not a big deal as one can always define a trivial layer that only scales an input or does some simple computation and use that layer to complete a task. I found that tf.variables outside a layer got optimised away by the compiler so there was no way to update post compilation.

b. The use of assign works well as an update device. I tried other approaches but I ended up with assign.

Here is a callback subclass that is consistent with the demo code. Note that when using the class you have to instantiate an instance of the class when calling `fit`. You cannot pass the name of the callback. Also note that this is not my real code but something I wrote to be consistent with the demo code above. It has not been tested and may have errors/typos.

```
class update_callback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None, steps=50):
        update_value = tf.clip_by_value(
            tf.cast((epoch + 1) / steps, dtype=tf.float32),
            clip_value_min=tf.constant(0.0, dtype=tf.float32),
            clip_value_max=tf.constant(1.0, dtype=tf.float32),
        ) # change this to what you want
        weighted_add_layer.weight.assign(update_value) #assign the update
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59246178/how-freeze-training-of-particular-layer-after-particular-epoches), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75361509/use-customcallback-class-to-achieve-freezing-layers-while-training/75361585#75361585) and related links in them, I don't think it is possible to freeze the layers *after* `model.compile()`. In your case, you have to save, freeze, then re-compile the model again.

Comment: It doesn't require to recompile. See the comment above.

Comment: Many thanks to both of you for responding!